# Please consider leaving comments if you routinely downvote the same person or people!

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, comments

Please leaving comments if you routinely downvote the same person or people!

1. Assume the person wants to learn if they keep asking questions
2. Assume the person can learn if they are not banned due to your voting
3. Consider how your own behaviour might be reflecting hasty generalizations etc.

Comment: this is so much fun, thanks for your help meta!

Comment: You throw sometimes complicated questions into a vacuum on a slow day and people may try to respond to you in one way or another, downvoting or with comments that are not on point.

Comment: You may encourage people even in other rooms study study Marx or some of the newer stuff on Marx. I think that would be good. However, like I told you some time ago, we don't seem to have many real Marx experts here, or if we do, they don't show themselves. So you may always be a bit frustrated here. Get used to it. We have a lot of science and math people at stack exchange so their interest may be more in narrow issues of philosophy of science, epistemology. Etc

Comment: makes sense @Gordon thanks, point taken!