# Fess up if the same person is downvoting so many of my questions

Tags: discussion, voting

Fess up if the same person is down-voting so many of my questions. Thanks. I very rarely get coherent comments explaining down-votes.

Comment: I empathize with the frustration!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is psychological venting.

Comment: Venting is occasionally useful...

Comment: This is essentially the same complaint as your previous questions:
[Is revenge voting against the rules or just unhelpful?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5052/13641)
[What's it going to take for people to sort out their erratic voting habits](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5015/13641)
[What was wrong with this question?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3923/13641) And especially [Please consider leaving comments if you routinely downvote the same person or people!](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3940/13641)

Comment: that's a fair point @curiousdannii i guess i am venting / looking for help that isn't forthcoming

Comment: To be frank, constantly (and vocally) demanding that you're give reasons for downvotes you is likely to lead to ***more*** downvotes so that people can take vicious delight in watching you have a tantrum every time you get a downvote.

Comment: how clever of them. it's not exactly "every time" @Valorum

Comment: @another_name - It's common enough that I recognised this post as you, despite only visiting occasionally. I'd seriously suggest that instead of ranting about downvotes, each time you get one, you spend a minute working out how you could improve your answers (better quotes, better formatting, clearer themes, solid conclusions backed up by evidence, etc) to turn those downvotes into upvotes.

Comment: And purely for the record, if your plan is to yell at anyone who downvotes you and demand that they be removed from the site, please don't expect them to tell you that they've downvoted.

Comment: i do think about how to improve my answers: i am not just being a jerk. moreover, i am not "yelling" i am not anyone should be "removed" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't expect explanations for downvotes. Downvotes mean one of three things:

- That someone was emotionally triggered by something in your post
- That you post was incoherent, inconsistent, or otherwise indecipherable and unanswerable
- That you failed to give a proper foundation, so that people are confused by what you wrote

In any case, the failure is yours for not providing a proper framework and argument. Reread your post, try to imagine what people object to, and edit/edit/edit.

I have not (that I remember) downvoted any of your posts. But your username sticks in my head, which means that I have found your posts problematic in the past (that's salience: human nature fixates on problematic material). I'd have to review your offerings to know what my personal quibbles are, but that's more or less irrelevant. If you are ticking people off enough for them to downvote you, you are doing something wrong, and it behooves you to reflect on what that 'wrongness' might be.

There is a fine but important line between making troubling but necessary points, and merely being troublesome. I have to walk that line as much as you do, so...

Comment: lol who gets triggered by me being an idiot?

Comment: @another_name — In my experience, there isn't *anything* that doesn't trigger *someone*. Like I said, frequently enough I trigger people — astonishing, because I'm obviously the soul of reason and common sense  — and then I always end up spending some time trying to figure out what I said that was triggering, and how I could have said it differently, and whether that triggering was an unfortunate but unavoidable consequence. You live and you learn, and if you learn better you live better.